# How to check the location of installed files when using Installer on Mac 10.6.7

Tags: mac, unix

I am installing a C++ library using the Installer application(its a .mpkg file)  The installation is successful, but I cannot find the location of the library to set an environmental variable. I have checked the /private/var/log/install.log, but the destination folder is not listed.  Is there another log I can check, or a way to determine the installation destination through the .mpkg? 
Thank you very much for your time, 
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply open the package with the standard OS X Installer, and hit ⌘I (or through menus: File>Show files).

For more information or to act upon the files, use the excellent [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) package manager.

Answer (score 7):

Use `pkgutil --pkg-info packageid` and look for the listed "location" to see where the installation root was; then `pkgutil --files packageid` will show the installed files *relative to* that root location.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/InsomniaT.mpkg/Contents/Resources/Kernel\ Module.pkg/Contents/
$ ls
Archive.bom    Archive.pax.gz Info.plist     PkgInfo        Resources
$ lsbom Archive.bom
.   41775   0/80
./System    40755   0/0
./System/Library    40755   0/0
./System/Library/Extensions 40755   0/0
./System/Library/Extensions/InsomniaT.kext  40755   0/0
./System/Library/Extensions/InsomniaT.kext/Contents 40755   0/0
./System/Library/Extensions/InsomniaT.kext/Contents/Info.plist  100644  0/0 1900    1578584638
./System/Library/Extensions/InsomniaT.kext/Contents/MacOS   40755   0/0
./System/Library/Extensions/InsomniaT.kext/Contents/MacOS/InsomniaT 100644  0/0 107860  966116348
$ gzip -cd Archive.pax.gz | pax | more
.
./System
./System/Library
./System/Library/Extensions
./System/Library/Extensions/InsomniaT.kext
./System/Library/Extensions/InsomniaT.kext/Contents
./System/Library/Extensions/InsomniaT.kext/Contents/Info.plist
./System/Library/Extensions/InsomniaT.kext/Contents/MacOS
./System/Library/Extensions/InsomniaT.kext/Contents/MacOS/InsomniaT
$
```

Comment: This only works on old-style (bundle-based) packages, and only shows the file paths relative to the installation root, and if the installation root wasn't "/"...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view the details of what was installed using `pkgutil`.

You can use `pkgutil --packages` to get the exact name of the package and then `pkgutil --files package` to see what files were installed.

Comment: that command just gives me the package names, not their destination